# утилита make не выполняется

Tags: golang, makefile

make не выполняет таргеты

```
commit := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)

all: fmt build 

fmt:
    go fmt ./...

build:
   echo $(commit)
   go build ./...

run:
   ./project
```

Вот и сам Makefile и результат его выполнения

```
 user@user-dev:~/Projects$ make
 go fmt ./...
 echo ef4876b
 ef4876b
 go build ./...
```

Ошибок не выдаёт,но в папке не появляется результата компиляции.
Что делать?

Comment: Утилита `make` как раз выполняется (вы же приводите результаты git и echo), а вот что делает утилита `go`?

Comment: *не появляется результата компиляции* — а каким образом выполняется эта самая ваша «компиляция»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тупанул немножечко:) не компиляции а билда

Comment: @avp "go build",как ни странно, билдит файлы формата типа .go в исполняемые файлы. и при вводе напрямую в bash работает отлично,нежели чем так

Comment: ну так и напишите `go build`, а не `go build ./...`, раз именно так «работает»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `go build ./...` не произведёт сборку бинарей в директориях и субдиректориях, а лишь проверяет, что они вообще билдятся:

> ```
> When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package,
> build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object,
> serving only as a check that the packages can be built.
> ```

— `go help build`

Чтобы собрать конкретный бинарь, укажите его явно:

```
go build ./cmd/foo
```